# How do you do more advance queries with Mongoose? Specifically a query using $or

Tags: mongodb, node.js, find, mongoose

I was learning some mongodb stuff, and it's pretty awesome!

I decided to try it out with mongoose in node and came upon the realization that I have no idea how to run an or command, so I looked up how you would do an or command in regular mongoose and found that the query is similar to this:

> db.meh.find({ $or : [ { a : 3 }, { b : 4 } ] });

And that seems to work great with the command line program for finding all entities where a == 3 or b == 4

But... How would I do this in mongoose?

Any help is appreciated!!

Note I also would like to be able to do this with the findOne() method, but I'm assuming that it'll act just the same as find() with a limit on it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Zimm!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It should be the same in mongoose.

```
SomeObjects.find({$or : [{a: 3}, {b: 4}]});
```

> Note I also would like to be able to do this with the findOne()
>   method, but I'm assuming that it'll act just the same as find() with a
>   limit on it

Yea, that should work as well.

Comment: sorry I can't up you, I'm too n00b :P

Comment: Mongoose is really nice as you can just use the queries like in the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 2):

i don't think you need to find anything here as mongoose has helpers for that (not sure if this was the case at the time of the post though):

`query.or([{ color: 'blue' }, { color: 'red' }]);`

[mongoose query doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or)